# Getc over-read a \n character

Tags: c, file-read, getc

I'm having some problems with this little function that can read a file:

```
void ReadFile(char *name) {
FILE *fr;
int lenght, i;
fr = fopen(name, "r");  //Open the file reader
fseek(fr, 0, 2);        //Set the pointer at the EOF
lenght = ftell(fr);     //Read the ending position
printf("\nDEBUG lenght:%d\n", lenght);
fseek(fr, 0, 0);        //Return at the beginning of the file

printf("File read:\n\n");
for (i = 1; i <= lenght; i++) {
    printf("%c", getc(fr));
    fseek(fr, i, 0);
}
fclose(fr);
}
```

This is the file that it reads:

```
qwerty

asdfgh
zxcvbn
```

But this is the output of the program:

```
DEBUG lenght:24
File read:

qwerty



asdfgh

zxcvbn
```

It is basically reading an extra "\n" when there is one before.
Any ideas of why the code doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: why is that fseek there? the one in the read loop

Comment: platform? windows?

Comment: you are messing up the reading by doing the extra `fseek(fr, i, 0);` in the for loop. Remove that and it will print what you expect.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I had to move the cursor "manually"

Comment: please post a [mcve] so we can easily reproduce the problem.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please indent the code consistently.  Indent after every opening brace '['.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'. Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces. 2) follow the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*

Comment: Most C library functions return a value,  That value can indicate success or failure.  Strongly suggest checking the returned value from `fopen()` `fseek()`  `ftell()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open a file in text mode (as you do), then a call to `fseek` may only contain offset values that have been previously retrieved by an `ftell` function (cf, for example, [cppreference/fseek](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek)):

> If the stream is open in text mode, the only supported values for
>   offset are zero (which works with any origin) and a value returned by
>   an earlier call to ftell on a stream associated with the same file
>   (which only works with origin of SEEK_SET).

In your `for`-loop, however, you are passing the value of `i`, which is not retrieved by `ftell`.

Besides that, your `fseek` in the loop is superflous, as `fgetc` moves the read pointer forward anyway. So `for (i = 1; i <= lenght; i++) { printf("%c", getc(fr)); }` should do the job.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tought that I had to move the cursor manually with getc. Thanks for the information on the offset value of fseek, I didn't knew that too

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. performs the desired functionality
3. properly checks for errors

and now, the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // EOF, fopen(), getc(), putc() fclose() puts() perror()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

// prototype
void ReadFile(char *filename);


void ReadFile(char *filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen( filename, "r" );

    if( !fp )
    {
        perror( "fopen failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    puts("File read:\n");

    int ch;
    while( (ch = getc( fp )) != EOF )
    {
        putchar( ch );
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```